# QML graphical editor issue / anyone have this issue?

Tags: c++, qml, qt5, qt-creator

I'm trying to edit my QML code within the designer. It stopped working out of nowhere.

There are no errors in the QML, and upon opening the designer tab, the designer opens 3 or more previews of my QML requiring me to close them and then displays nothing in the actual designer box. Has any one of you encountered these issues and possibly have a fix for them? I prefer to use the designer to edit the QML, but i will write all of it if i need to.

Thank you.

as Shown:
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Which version of QtCreator is this? Which plugins are enabled? I can see by the double Welcome icon on the left that you have the StudioWelcome plugin enabled.

Comment: 7.0.3, with 5.12.2 kit installed. Only plugin i enabled was all of the "QtQuick" ones to enable the designer

Comment: Just disabled the Studiowelcome plugin and nothing changed.

Comment: Correction* im using qtcreator 7.0.2

Comment: I tried downgrading to QTcreator 6, and even 5 and had the same issue

Comment: Here is a QtCreator bugreport which explains the issue in the comments. You might be able to create a solution for your case https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTCREATORBUG-26486
You should probably use the community version of QtDesignStudio in order to have a WYSIWYG editor for QML.

Comment: For some reason QT designer likes to break when you're editing a QML file with a "Window{}" structure. I fixed this issue by separating the initialization of child components and window.